# Using php's magic methods outside a class

Tags: php, magic-methods

Is it possible to use PHP magic methods (specifically __get()) outside a defined class?

I'm wanting to use it in a configuration file for quick loading.  The configuration file has a single array, $config, with many keys.  Therefore, I'd like to override __get() to return the key in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could write an object that reads the config file, and provides the __get method.